# Can't figure out why my materials render out grey in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

Just started blender - This is what the glass material part is rendering out to.
They're made to be transparent (like glass) in shader which shows up in render view, but when I go to render image it's a blocky gray - sorry stupid question can't figure it out!!

Comment: What are you trying to create ?Share your node setup and a screenshot of your viewport to make it more clear.It is difficult to judge just by seeing that picture

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 Hi my bad and thanks for replying, I created a "gundam helmet" kind of thing using planes and I'm trying to put the 3d render over a photograph. Photo is on a plane using image texture, but helmet materials turn out grey when rendered. I also just realized that when I exit out of camera perspective, everything turns pink in the shading viewport and completely transparent in the render viewport. Not sure if I need to restart? Seems like a lot is going wrong, here are some screenshots of the helmet in the diff viewports if it helps..https://imgur.com/a/PJDe6dJ
Thank you!

Comment: Can't say what it happening for sure it appears that there is more than one problem going on...Have you enabled Transparent background option in film?Try going to the rendered view after disabling it.